# Probability of One pair hand in Poker 5 cards

Tags: combinatorics

I have been working on the problem of probability of poker hands,

I have been able to calculate the probability of each hand except one pair and high card hand.

Here is what I have

P1 P2 X1 X2 X3(here P1 P2 are the same)

> 13C1 * 4C2  (total counts of one pair)

Now total counts of 3 cards distinct from the pair cards

> **(12C1 * 4) * (11C1 * 4) * (10C1 * 4) / ??**

obviously there is repetition in the second term, How do I remove it?

According to [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_probability) ?? valus is 6, I am not able to understand How to arrive at that value

In case of Triple hand, I did this

> (13C1 * 4C3) * **(12C1 * 11C1)/2**  * 4C1 * 4C1

because in this case each terms is counted twice in case of Two distinct cards.

Can someone please help me out here?

Comment: In problems of this kind one usually asks for counting hands that have a pair and not anything better.  Likewise for a high-card hand, which amounts to not having any pair or better, i.e. also no flush and no straight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way to look at it: There are $\binom{13}{1}$ ways to pick which type of card ($2$, $Q$, etc.) your pair will be, and $\binom{12}{3}$ ways to choose the types of your other cards (so that you will have a pair, instead of a full house, three-of-a-kind, etc.). There are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to choose the suits of your paired cards and $\binom{4}{1}$ ways to choose the suit of any one of your $3$ non-paired cards. Hence, the answer is $$\binom{13}{1}\cdot\binom{12}{3}\cdot\binom{4}{2}\cdot\binom{4}{1}^3.$$

**Note**: $\binom{n}{r}$ is an alternate notation for $_nC_r$.

---

As for high-card hand, it's probably simpler *not* to calculate it directly. You say you've calculated all other hand types, so just subtract them all from the total number of possible hand types--that is, from $\binom{52}{5}$.

Comment: Oh ok, How did I not think of it :(. Many thanks

Comment: Any time. If it makes you feel better, I used to do it the way you did it, before someone else pointed out the obvious (in hindsight) to me.

Comment: Actually I liked wiki's calculation for the High Card, (13C5 - 10)*(4^5-4)

Comment: Oh, that *is* nice!

Comment: this is not a probability, this value is greater than 1

Comment: @AlexanderMills, that's true, but a probability isn't actually what the OP asked for. Rather, it was asked *how many* hands of the given types were possible.

Comment: Well I think OP was asking about probability, but I believe you just divide it by (52 choose 5) and it will be fine?

Comment: @AlexanderMills, correct. And I suppose it would have been more accurate to say that, while the OP asked about probability, all of the calculations shown were finding numbers of hands, instead, so I inferred that I wouldn't need to explain how to convert into a probability from there.

Answer (score 1):

Your calculations are right.
And the value you represented with "??" is 6 indeed.
It is 6 because you have $3\cdot 2\cdot 1$ ways of ordering the extra cards (and in poker, order of cards clearly does not matter).